# How to go directly on a certain page no.?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am using python3 selenium. They are using this to navigate to another page "__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gvSearchDentistlist','Page$5')".

Here is the link of page.I wanted to go on page 5 directly.

https://dciindia.gov.in/DentistsSearch.aspx?Reg_Type=D&RegUnder=0&IDRId=&IDRName=&CourseId=0&RegDate=0&CouncilId=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.get('https://dciindia.gov.in/DentistsSearch.aspx?Reg_Type=D&RegUnder=0&IDRId=&IDRName=&CourseId=0&RegDate=0&CouncilId=')

javascript= "__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gvSearchDentistlist', 'Page$5')"

driver.execute_script(javascript)
input()
```

if you inspect that page hyper links you can see it use javascript , just call that function from script as above :

[image]

## if you want to call page 11 change 'Page$5' to 'Page$11'